# Support for Legacy Capabilities is deprecated; You are sending "deviceName" which is an invalid capability

Tags: java, automation, appium

I was trying to setup a project with Java and Appium. Thing is that I am just learning it and I got stuck on first few lines of the code
[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEDRq.png)

I am trying to set the "Desired Capabilities" but there is an issue stating that these are invalid capabilities. I have tried to look into the docs as well but cannot figure out how to fix it. Would be great help if anyone can help it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding "appium:" to the capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("appium:deviceName", "deviceName");
cap.setCapability("appium:app", fs.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get instance from **UiAutomator2Options** class to applies specific capabilities instead of **DesiredCapabilities** when you get instance from AndroidDriver.

https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/legacy-protocol-support/

```
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
options.setDeviceName("testemulator");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a change to the "latest" tag for  selenium/standalone-chrome which is causing this problem.

Try pulling a prior version. I had your the same error you had with "latest" but I pulled "101.0.4951.41" and my tests are working again.

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling a prior version. I had your the same error you had with "latest" but I pulled "101.0.4951.41" and my tests are working again.

Hi, It's not clear to me. Prior version of what please.